# How can I keep a php form process script from being processed alone, without being called from its html page?

Tags: php, forms, process

I've been ask to troubleshoot a problem on a very, very old html website which I did not build. There are two html forms which each call their own php scripts to process them. They have been getting empty form submissions. I put code in place to make three of the fields mandatory as well as added a captcha form. When you go through the normal process, these measures work to stop empty form submissions. However, they are still getting empty form submissions. I discovered that if you enter the script url directly in a browser, for example form-process.php, it does submit the empty form without the mandatory fields nor the captcha.

Any suggestions on keeping this script from running on it's own?

Thank you in advance.
PS, I am a php novice, so the php for dummies version would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you prefer a link or to have me paste code here?

Comment: Edit and paste.  I assume by add captcha and required fields, you only did this in the form not the PHP?

Comment: I believe there would be a simple answer and a complicated answer to this question. My one solution would be to offer the idea of using PHP's `isset()` method to verify there are `<form>` variables sent to the PHP page. This still wont address the issue of spamming fake data. At any rate I think the best solution will be to just reduce the amount of junk received...

Comment: I added the required code directly to the html forms. The captcha was added to the html form and the check of the captcha field was added to the php process script.

Comment: There is actually very few of these submissions. The two forms are submitted at approximately the same time, and all of the fields are always blank. Could these be triggered by a crawl or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things (either or and)

1. Use **htaccess** to stop users from running it
2. If the mandatory fields are not there, then don't save the form.  Just check and stop execution on the first line.

For more detailed help, you need to receiprocate and provide more details :-)

Comment: Thank you Rohit. I used method 2 and believe it's working. I'll know in a day or two if the empty submissions stop.

Comment: Rohit or anyone, I used method 2 because I wasn't sure how to set up the .htaccess file. Out of curiosity, and for the sake of learning, what would you put in the .htaccess file. The four files are in the root directory and for simplicity, let's call them form1.html, form2.html, form1-process.php and form2-process.php. Thanks. I'm sure others could benefit from the advice as well.